# Solving diffusion equation for a semi infinite tube filled with water with a source of ink pouring ink into the tube

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, mathematical-physics, diffusion

I am trying to understand diffusion in a semi infinite space.Suppose we have a semi infinite horizontal tube with a valve filled with water just like this:

[image]

Suppose we start pouring black ink into the tube such as the concentration $C$ at $x=0$ to be constant in $t$.Lets assume that $C(x,0)=\delta(x)$.So we have chosen our boundary condition.If the concentration at $x=0$ is 0 at all times then the eigenfunction will be $B \sin (kx),k>0$ so the solution will be in the form of $\int_{0}^{\infty}B \sin (kx) e^{-k^{2}t}dk$

But obviously $C(0,t)\ne 0$ so we have a inhomogenous condition.So how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you asking about the solution for a certain amount of added ink (rather than a certain fixed concentration at the boundary)? Or are you asking how multiple additions of sin(0) can possibly add up to a nonzero number? Or something else? Please clarify.